# Issue with Custom Error setting on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, custom-errors

I'm having a really wierd error with Custom errors setting on IIS 7. I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application which uses JavaScript/Ajax/Jquery. 
    I am trying to move my hosting over to another provider and am testing to ensure everything works fine.  When the custom errors setting is 'OFF' everything works fine.
  However setting it to 'ON' with a redirect is causing the JavaScript that is in the View to be displayed at the top of the screen!  This is my custom errors setting below:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Errors/Error/Index">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Errors/Error/Error404"></error>
    </customErrors>
```

For what it's worth, I've got exactly the same settings on my current provider and it works perfectly fine!  So I'm at a loss to understand what's happening. Unfortunately my hosting provider doesn't seem to understand the issue either. Please can somebody help?

EDIT:  When I remove the defaultRedirect attribute and the error element, it works fine.  It just doesn't seem to like the attribute or element.

Thank You,

Comment: Move the answer to an answer below and accept it.